# Get result from query using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

My program contains a gridview of rows of which I want to check if they are already billed.

I do this by checking a column in which the ID of the item is stored.

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getBilledItem]
    @itemID int 
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT [items].[dbo].[itemLine].itemID
    FROM [items].[dbo].[itemLine]
    WHERE description LIKE '%' + cast(@itemID AS VARCHAR(255)) + '%'

END
```

What I want to do in my program is to add the itemID when the stored procedure returns `1 row(s) affected` but this doesn't work.

My code looks like:

```
 using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString))
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("getBilledItem", conn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                })
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@itemID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = itemID;
                    conn.Open();

                    int amount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (amount > 0)
                    {
                        AlreadyBilledIDs.Add(itemID.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

Even when my stored procedure does return a row, my program doesn't catch it.

What in my code am I doing wrong? I thought that `CommandExecuteNonQuery` would return the amount of affected rows? Why isn't this working in my case?

Comment: Your procedure won't pass a rowcount back to your application at all if you have `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the procedure.

Comment: thanks for your reply @TabAlleman but setting it off didn't work

Comment: Well, your question is self-contradictory.   Are you looking for the amount of affected rows, or are you looking for the itemID?   They are not the same.

Comment: let's assume the select query will always return maximum 1 row (if condition is met)

Comment: Re-read the documentation on `ExecuteNonQuery`.. It doesn't do what you think it does.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I see `The number of rows affected.`?

Comment: Yeah:   "For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. "    Not SELECT statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method which is used when we have only one row with one column being returned or if we have multiple rows in that case too it will just selected first column of the first row.

So you can do :

```
int amount = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

if you need number of rows then you can use [`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql) in your stored procedure and the c# code will remain same, just modify your query to be:

```
SELECT Count([items].[dbo].[itemLine].itemID)
.............
.............
```

now you will have the total number of rows returned by query :

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```